# Android: how to save image in my created folder with its actual size

Tags: android, copy, photo, android-camera

I want to save my photo in my created folder with its actual size. For this I tried lots of code but in all case photo saved in gallery with its actual size but when I saved this photo in my location then photo get compressed.
After that I tried to copy photo from Gallery to my folder to get photo with its actual size. In this case photo is copping but not with its actual size. It again get compressed.
For opening the camera:

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, "Select Picture"),
            CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

after that in **onActivityResult** method :

```
try {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            if (photo != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            // Image name

            final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            final String[] p1 = new String[] {
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN };
            Cursor c1 = cr.query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null,
                    null, p1[1] + " DESC");
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/"
                        + c1.getInt(0);
                Uri newuri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);
                // Log.i("TAG", "newuri "+newuri);
                String snapName = getRealPathFromURI(newuri);

                Uri u = Uri.parse(snapName);

                File f = new File("" + u);
                String fileName = f.getName();

                editTextPhoto.setText(fileName);
                checkSelectedItem = true;

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* ignored for PNG */,
                        bos);
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                // Storing Image in new folder


//  StoreByteImage(mContext, bitmapdata, 100, fileName);


                copyImageFromGallery(newuri);






                // To appear images in created folder of Gallery dynamically
                // as soon as they
                // are captured.
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://"
                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

                // Delete the image from the Gallery

                getContentResolver().delete(newuri, null, null); // for delete

            }
            c1.close();

        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in creating Image." + e);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in creating Image." + e);
    }
```

now I copying my Image form Gallery to my folder:

```
protected void copyImageFromGallery(Uri uri){

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String sourceImagePath= uri.toString();


            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pix/images");
                if (!sdImageMainDirectory.exists()) {
                    sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
                }



            String destinationImagePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pix/images";
            File source= new File(data, souceImagePath);
            File destination= new File(sd, destinationImagePath);
            if (source.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 100, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
    }} catch (Exception e) {}


    }
```

here photo is copying in my folder but till it compressed.

Answer (score 0):

use `cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);` here outputFile Uri is the location of the file that you want to save.

Comment: previously I used this code but this code also save photo in compressed format.

Comment: I dont know exactly, but i think there should be something like cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_QUALITY,1) where 1 is for high quality and 0 for low quality. but not sure. check it once

Comment: here my Eclipse show that "EXTRA_QUALITY cannot be resolved or is not a field". EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY is there which is for video.

Comment: What about EXTRA_IMAGE_QUALITY ?

Comment: i donno. I never used. but thought something should be there. If there is VIDEO_QUALITY there should be something for IMAGE_QUALITY...

Comment: you have to search in the documents of MediaStore(Android Developers) and make sure if there is any Extra Constant about image quality